# Volume/Day on a Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kdc

Our Kafka is KDC Integrated in linux environment and RBAC is managed under Windows Active Directory Server.
Using KAfka Admin API is it possible to get this data?

Answer (score 1):

KDC isn't relevant to cluster metrics.

You can get bytes-in from aggregating broker JMX metrics, not with AdminClient